# How can I manage memory in a loop under ARC without @autoreleasepool block

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

As before, we usually do something for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++) {
    NSNumber * number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];
    [muArray addObject:number];
    [number release];
}
```

But under ARC, there is no `release`. Can I manage memory without an `@autorelease` block, like this (directly remove release statement):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++) {
    NSNumber * number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];
    [muArray addObject:number];
}
```

---

Similarly, is the `@autoreleasepool` necessary, like this?

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++) {
    @autoreleasepool{
        NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        [muArray addObject:number];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code block (compiled with ARC), has exactly the same semantics as your first code block (compiled with MRC).

Under ARC, when you set a strong object reference to nil, **or when a strong object reference is destroyed**, ARC takes care of sending the `release` message for you.  In both examples, the `number` variable is destroyed at the end of the loop body, so (in the second example) ARC releases the objected that `number` referenced.

In your third example, the `@autoreleasepool` will cause the returned `NSNumber` to be released on each pass through the loop.  This might be necessary for a large number of loop iterations.  For just five iterations, each creating a single `NSNumber`, it's not necessary.

Comment: I have a question. Does it exist a potential problem If I modify the code like this:<p>
`for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++) {
NSNumber * number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];
[muArray addObject:number];
number = nil;
}`

Comment: No problem exists.  The assignment of `nil` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer at first. But I mean to the third example, is it exist a memory management problem if I remove the '@autoreleasepool' block? I suppose there are a large number of 'NSNumber' objects in the loop now, and they both use autoreleased constructor. That situation will cause high maximum memory usage in loop within MRC mode. Is it working well for a large number of `NSNumber` objects in a loop without '@autoreleasepool' in ARC mode?

Comment: “Is it working well” - the answer depends on your app.  You need to test your app, and maybe run it under the Allocations instrument, to figure out whether it's a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ARC will translate your second example into the first.

You can read more [here (apple docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) and [here (dr. dobbs)](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/automatic-reference-counting-on-ios/240000820).

The autorelease pool example is should also be equivalent, [llvm docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#autoreleasepool)